# Splunk integration with Oozie

Tags: oozie, splunk

We need to capture Oozie workflow Failure events in Splunk - HTTP Event Collector (Example: https://qa.splunk.organization.com/services/collector).

To achieve this, we created a separate Oozie Java action to log the failure event to Splunk. The problem with this approach is, we have more than 100 oozie workflows and adding a new workflow action for Splunk is not feasible.

Is there any better approach to capture Oozie workflow failure in Splunk HTTP Event Collector?

> Workflow.xml

```
    <start to="Input_Check" />
    <decision name="Input_Check">
        <switch>
            <case to="Input_Move"> ${fs:dirSize(source_hdfs_path) gt 0} </case>
            <default to="end"/>
        </switch>
    </decision>

    <action name="Input_Move">
        <java>
            <main-class>com.org.FileMove</main-class>
            <arg>${source_hdfs_path}/</arg>
            <arg>${destination_hdfs_path}</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="Process_File" />
        <error to="Splunk_Log" />
    </action>

    <action name="Process_File">
        <java>
            <main-class>com.org.FileProcessor</main-class>
            <arg>inputPath=${destination_hdfs_path}/</arg>
            <arg>outputPath=${output_hdfs_path}/</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="Splunk_Log" />
    </action>

    <action name="Splunk_Log">
        <java>
            <main-class>com.org.SplunkLog</main-class>
            <arg>https://qa.splunk.organization.com/services/collector</arg>
            <arg>auth-token</arg>
            <arg>Workflow Failed</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="fail"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Test Splunk Workflow failed</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

> Java Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class SplunkLog {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if(args.length!=3){
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        String URL = args[0];
        String authToken = args[1];
        String data = args[2];

        String jsonData = "{\"event\": \"" + data + "\", \"sourcetype\": \"manual\"}";

        URL url = new URL (URL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Splunk " + authToken);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.connect();

        OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(jsonData);
        writer.close();
        outputStream.close();

        if (connection.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        }else{
            System.out.println("data : " + jsonData + "token : " + authToken);
            System.out.println("ERROR : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You mean, like polling the Oozie server every X minutes to list the last N workflows with status FAILED or KILLED, then matching with previously recorded failures, to get the new failures? Then retrieving details about these new failures and sending a notification to Splong?

Comment: Note that an Action inside a workflow could not report a KILLED status. Nor a SUSPENDED ones. Although these may have some interest for Ops monitoring..

Comment: Hi Samson, updated my question with the workflow and java code where we log our alert

Comment: This updates brings NO useful information. Your issue is to choose between an "in-Workflow" approach, that requires a lot of refactoring and will not cover edge cases (Oozie server crash, YARN failure leading to SUSPENDED status, etc); and an external service that polls the Oozie server globally. Make your choice. Then develop some code.